# Can we use Kafka Streams state-store as a cache? Or use state-store as a means of deduplicating messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am developing a kafka streams based application. I need to identify and filter out duplicate messages that I might receive.

I have read that Kafka streams uses a state-store to persist state of computations/aggregations. I was wondering if we can use this state-store to do message deduplication.

i.e something like below

```
private boolean isDuplicate(String key, String event) {
  if(stateStore.get(key)!=null) {
     return false;
  } else {
    stateStore.put(key);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Even if I can do this what are performance and resiliency related implications of this? My application is going to handle around 50 million records a day. If I keep storing keys like this in state-store for deduplication will I run out of memory or disk will become full?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing preventing this from working is cardinality of your keyspace in relation to available memory or disk, assuming you're using persistent Statestore (RocksDB).

Resiliency is hard because if you relocate or scale your app, then it needs to be able to quickly reload your store on every machine, which may take hours at 50M records per day, but maybe less after topic compaction

Comment: But then what I don't get is, Kafka streams uses this same state-store. And I can transparently scale my application up and down by adding/removing consumers on the fly. So then how these state-stores are synced so fast such that when new consumer is added it understands what the state of aggregation/computation was?

Comment: You can only scale up to the number of partitions in a topic, and cannot easily be done "on the fly"... Each store is written on-disk, per consumed partition. Kafka consumers can read thousands of events per second per-partition...